# How do you mathematically formalize standard concepts?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-modeling, advice

Is there a look-up table or reference of formalizations that describe standard conceptual modules? For example, I'm performing a classification of some set of features and it seems like there must be an accepted notation for this operation.

I looked at [How do you go about formalizing a concept?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921568/how-do-you-go-about-formalizing-a-concept), which is helpful but I'm asking about non-novel concepts that are easily abstractable and standard (I'm coming from computer science).

Comment: It might help if you give an example of a (concept, formalization) pair you'd hope such a source to contain. (If you're struggling to think of one, trying to identify which otherwise unformalized concept is formalized in a formalization with which you're already familiar.) Would "(set theory, ZFC)" be an example, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @J.G. I have a classification function that classifies based on some set of features. I get a label from that classification function: 

F(a,b,c) = u
where u is a label.

This kind of thing must be very common, but my notation in my paper is awkward and I don't know where to look for better examples

Comment: Oh, a classification *on* the feature set, not *of* it. Try each "multi" bullet point [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking about formal notation for an academic paper.

Comment: Easily done once you have your terms; see examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#Transformation_to_binary) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier).

Comment: Thanks! So you think the way to go here is (1) determine what structure you're formalizing then (2) go to the wiki entry for that structure and fill in the symbols?

Comment: If that doesn't work, at least you can ask a more specific question.